# I can not get to my MEW using Ledger Nano S

Tags: myetherwallet

When I want to open my wallet using ledger, it says that "No Compatible devices were found"( it is just in Slovak language), however my ledger works as I am using it with another wallets. It only doesn't work with your new interface. Everything worked fine with old interface. 
Can anybody help me to get to my wallet?
Thanks,